# Chrome browser bookmarks on android

Tags: android, google-chrome

I have two profiles in Google Chrome. I am trying to load a different profile on the Chrome browser for Android but I cannot find the option to do so. I need to load the bookmarks from a specific profile.

No documentation available for this procedure.
Thanks

P.S. I am trying to build an android app to import all bookmarks from Chrome.

Comment: I already have signed into the Account properly with everything getting synced. Even Google Currents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clear about what you are asking. Are you wanting to sync your saved bookmarks? For Android: menu> settings> sign in to chrome >sync (select 'open tabs').

Scratch that- I understand what you are asking. You want to import bookmarks between two separate Google chrome accounts. I have been testing this and so far I see no clear method of syncing across two Chrome accounts within Chrome.

However, we could always find a way around it, strangely enough, using a completely different browser. How about first exporting the bookmarks from the original account as an HTML file. Using Firefox (if you have the Google Toolbar plugin), you could then import *that* to Google Bookmarks. Now open Firefox and click 'bookmarks', then 'organize bookmarks'. Select the HTML file. In Google Chrome, go to the Toolbar, click bookmarks, and import the Firefox bookmarks (which are technically the bookmarks from your original Google chrome account).

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I am already aware of this. The thing is I just wanted to compare the results with the output using Chrome Bookmarks plugin.

Comment: The users can verify in the Phone itself. i.e. They should sync properly using *different* profiles. TYPO: it should be Chrome Bookmarks API.

Comment: Got it. I seem to know the issue. The other account I have is a company account. This one syncs via Google Device Policy; what is getting sync'd is highly ambiguous. Even though it says Sync Bookmarks, I don't see any. I can just see Contact list and emails. Nothing else. Anyways, I going to accept your answer since it is workaround for the problem.

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't be of greater help to you, but great, you discovered the issue! Hopefully, Google Chrome will further optimize syncing between accounts in the future.

Comment: no worries, dude. I am hoping great things from Chrome for Android too. Firefox was the first game-changer, but Chrome is plain awesome. Cheers.